# How to handle session timeout in a Laravel application

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a Laravel 9 application that uses vue. I make exteensive use of AJAX calls (through jQuery) in the vue components to fetch the required data. I also use a Javascript timer (setInterval) that makes an Ajax call to fetch updated notifications data. This is my typical Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/user/currentUserInfoAndNotifications",
            headers: {
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr(
                    "content"
                ),
            },
            method: "post",
            data: {
                 ...
            },

            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                // data received
                .... 
                
                }
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (data) {
                // may happen due to session timeout or other situations..
                // How to detect??
                
            }.bind(this),
        });
```

The timer may make a call to thus AJAX call every minute. Meanwhile, the session may timeout and the call will fail.

My question is how to detect timeout or other error conditions in my AJAX calls.

Besides, since my application has 100s of AJAX calls, I would prefer if I can detect this situation at a central place, e.g. routes/web.php (All my routes are contained in this file), so that when ajax makes a call and it comes to routes/web.php, I can detect session timeout situation and logout the user and redirect the user to the session timeout page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your `error` callback function like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/user/currentUserInfoAndNotifications",
    headers: {
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
    },
    method: "post",
    data: { ... },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        // Handle successful response
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Handle error
        if (xhr.status === 401) {
            // Session has timed out
            // Refresh page or do what you need here...
        } else {
            // Other error condition
            // Display error message or take other appropriate action
        }
    }
});
```

> Note: Sending a request every time to display a notification is an impractical method, as it may not result in the immediate display of the notification at the moment it occurs. You can improve your way to handle notifications by read more
> about [Laravel Event Broadcasting with Socket.io and Redis Example](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/real-time-event-broadcasting-with-laravel-6-and-socketioexample.html).

Comment: This will work. However, implementing error handling in over 100 Ajax calls will be cumbersome. I have found a way to handle this though Laravel, as explained in https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-handle-session-timeout-in-laravel-9-application

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle session timeout through Laravel is through middlewareGroups in Kernel.php, as given in https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-handle-session-timeout-in-laravel-9-application

Comment: Initially, I thought that this solution will work. After some testing, it appears NOT TO BE working. Could someone please have a look at the link and give inputs. Also, looks like that Laravel has built-in session timeout handling, which redirects the user to the login page after session timeout (at least if one is using Auth).